# The Error returned was:   Access denied for user 'Fox'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: dle

Вчера сайт работал как положено, а вечером вместо него появилось вот это

### MySQL Error!

The Error returned was: Access denied for user 'Fox'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Error Number: 1

Движок DLE 9.5 с лицензией, сайт http://www.genosse.su/для просмотра сайта пароль не нужен. Админпанель тоже не работает (нет запроса авторизации, а есть только эта ошибка

Comment: ну очевидно что то с mysql, запущен? Пароль не меняли? Сеть не трогали?

Comment: да поменяли пароль, этж очевидно. заходи в mysql    mysql -u root или     mysql -u root -p далее     use mysql;    update user set password=PASSWORD("тут пароль из конфига DLE 9.5") where User='Fox' and host='localhost';    flush privileges;    quit

Comment: так-то да, только кто ж вас пустит на хостинге рутом? я думаю, что речь идёт именно о случае на хостинге. Можно попробовать указать имя хоста базы данных "mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p и попробовать законектиться. Но это только в качестве теста, что настройки самого движка верны. Ну а по существу вопроса - в саппорт надо обращаться, коль пароль забыли.